# Chemfig arrow has a gap

Tags: chemfig

I got the following problem. When I draw a <-> arrow with chemfig it has a gap in the middle. The funny thing is the gap is only if my arrow goes from right to left. Vertical arrows are drawn properly. I have made an example but in the example it is  the other way around. The arrow from left to right is not fully drawn while from right to left is.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\begin{document}    
\schemestart
    \chemfig{*6(------)}
    \arrow{<->}
    \chemfig{*6(------)}
    \arrow{<->}[90]
    \chemfig{*6(------)}
    \arrow{<->}[180]
    \chemfig{*6(------)}
\schemestop
\end{document}
```

[image: Example]

Does anyone have an idea? I went throgh the documentation of chemfig already but couldnt find anything.
Greetings
Moritz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: The issue described in the question is reproducible with version `1.31` of chemfig (from where the 'original definition'  of the `<->` arrow is taken). With version `1.34` ther issue does not occur any more and the desired output is obtained.

---

The following example contains a modified version of the `<->` arrow type that does not show the gap if it is rotated by 180°

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{chemfig}

\makeatletter
\definearrow3{<->}{%
    \CF@arrow@shift@nodes{#3}%
    \path(\CF@arrow@start@node)--(\CF@arrow@end@node)%
            node[pos=0.5,sloped](\CF@arrow@start@node1){}node[pos=0.5,sloped](\CF@arrow@end@node1){};%
    \expandafter\draw\expandafter[\CF@arrow@current@style](\CF@arrow@start@node1)--(\CF@arrow@end@node);%
    \expandafter\draw\expandafter[\CF@arrow@current@style](\CF@arrow@end@node1)--(\CF@arrow@start@node);%
    \CF@arrow@display@label{#1}{0.5}+\CF@arrow@start@node{#2}{0.5}-\CF@arrow@end@node
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}    
\schemestart
    \chemfig{*6(------)}
    \arrow{<->}[0]
    \chemfig{*6(------)}
    \arrow{<->}[-90]
    \chemfig{*6(------)}
    \arrow{<->}[180]
    \chemfig{*6(------)}
\schemestop
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you compare this with the original definition from `chemfig.tex`

```
\definearrow3{<->}{%
    \CF@arrow@shift@nodes{#3}%
    \path(\CF@arrow@start@node)--(\CF@arrow@end@node)%
            node[pos=0.5,sloped,xshift=-1pt](\CF@arrow@start@node1){}node[pos=0.5,sloped,xshift=1pt](\CF@arrow@end@node1){};%
    \expandafter\draw\expandafter[\CF@arrow@current@style](\CF@arrow@start@node1)--(\CF@arrow@end@node);%
    \expandafter\draw\expandafter[\CF@arrow@current@style](\CF@arrow@end@node1)--(\CF@arrow@start@node);%
    \CF@arrow@display@label{#1}{0.5}+\CF@arrow@start@node{#2}{0.5}-\CF@arrow@end@node
}
```

you can see, that I have removed the `xshift` options.

Comment: This looks very advanced (+1) but could you perhaps explain a bit more? Do you think there is a bug in `chemfig`? And could you perhaps explain why it is necessary to draw a double-headed arrow in this way? Ti*k*Z does support double-headed arrows out of the box.

Comment: @marmot: To be honest, the above example is just the result of me experimenting with the original code of the `<->` type arrow. I noticed the `xshift` option and suspected this to be the culprit for the gap.